# Proper way to say one 1.5 times more?

Tags: word-usage

Temperature was very low, but now...?

> - Temperature has risen in a half as much again
> - Temperature has risen in one and a half times
> - Temperature has risen by half

Or... I don't know.

Comment: This is a long-standing question.  You can say that the value is now 1.5 times its previous value (if that's what you mean), or that it has risen by half.  Other phrasings tend to be ambiguous.  (But it should be noted that it's meaningless to say that temperature has risen by a factor of 1.5 unless you're speaking of "absolute" temperature.)

Comment: Half again as much.

Comment: @Robusto But only in Kelvin. :)

Comment: As everyone has pointed out, temperature is a particularly bad choice for this question. You might want to change that to something where we all agree on the definition of zero, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Why complicate matters?  Simplicity is always appreciated.

- The temperature was very low, around 30ºF, but now it must be about 45ºF.

but, if you prefer,

- "The temperature today has risen by 50% compared to yesterday". This sounds weird, though.

Comment: Since 30ºF is 272 K and 45ºF is 280 K, the temperature has only increased by 8 parts in 272. :)

Answer (score 1):

Half more than X means 1.5 times X.

[image]

Comment: So I can say "Temperature now is half more than it was a minute ago"?

Comment: Not a good plan; "half more" sounds to me like 19th century English. Say "The temperature is one and a half times what it was a minute ago."

Comment: @Miele - A physicist would give you a strange look.  Room temperature is 293 Kelvin.  50% more would be 439.5, which would be 146.5 Celsius or 295.7 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: @Miele the temperature example is just a very poor one because the conventional scales are not absolute. A better example would be that if a cylinder circumscribes a sphere, the cylinder's volume is half more than the sphere's.

Answer (score 1):

Temperatures are tricky.  Thirty degrees above zero doesn't represent thirty of anything; starting from the lowest that a temperature can be (i.e. absolute zero  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero), it actually represents nearly 500 units.  Thus, an increase of 15 units does not represent a one-and-one-half-fold increase at all.  So avoid that construct, since it is scientifically inaccurate.

Now if you actually have 45 of a tangible item (apples or oranges, let's say) and that's up from 30 previously, you can say **a 50% increase**.

Comment: 30ºF to 45ºF is +¹⁄₃₄ warmer. :)

Comment: This is way more technical than most English speakers would bother with.

Answer (score 1):

In general with quantities the following are correct and unambiguous:

- It has increased by half
- It is increased by half as much again
- It has increased to one-and-a-half times the amount

Note the prepositions. Technically neither of the first two sentences in the question are right. "Increased by half" is less clear because it might mean "increased by half a unit" (i.e. half a degree in the case of temperature), though most people wouldn't understand it like that. Using synonyms like 'risen' or '50%' make no difference.

Temperature is less clear-cut from a scientific point of view because is is an arbitrary scale. For common usage this isn't generally a problem, though you might want to avoid such comparisons in anything close to scientific literature.